# Reference Error :cy is not defined while running cypress test

Tags: cypress

```
Describe('The Login', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        cy.readFile(Cypress.env('test')).as("user")});

    it("Login", () => {
        cy.get("@user").then((user) =>
        cy.login(user.username, user.password))})
```

FAIL  cypress/integration/login.spec.js
  ● The Login Page ›

```
ReferenceError: cy is not defined

  at Object.<anonymous> (cypress/integration/login.spec.js:4:5)
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: You need to put in more details like code to reproduce, error from the console.

Comment: added the details

Answer (score 6):

To add some context to the answer by @sai, to resolve this eslint error all I had to do was install eslint-plugin-cypress [from here](https://github.com/cypress-io/eslint-plugin-cypress).

```
npm install eslint-plugin-cypress --save-dev
```

Then, in my eslint config I added one line to my extends array.

> Your config could be .eslintrc.json or the "eslintConfig" configuration object in your package.json

```js
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:cypress/recommended"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing locally, this should work for you. Change path of your json file, and use your custom command cy.login. In my example I just printed variables to console.

```
describe('The Login', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
      cy.readFile('cypress/integration/test/test.json').as("user")});
  it("Login", () => {
      cy.get("@user").then((user) =>
      cy.log(user.username, user.pass))
    })
  })
```

My test.json was:

```
{
  "username":"test@test.com",
  "pass":"pass"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The issue was related to eslint
Had to install few packages and made an update to eslintrc files

Comment: I have the same issue. Which packages did you install and what did you update in the eslintrc file?

Comment: See my answer for more details @Arek https://stackoverflow.com/a/60131233/2684661